# Free Poisson Distribution

Tags: probability, random-variables, poisson-distribution

For some $\lambda$, suppose for each $n > \lambda$, there are independent random variables $(Z_{j,n})_{j = 1}^n$ such that

$$
P(Z_{j,n} = 1) = 1 - P(Z_{j,n} = 0) = \frac\lambda n
$$

I am trying to calculate
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} P(\sum_{j=1}^n Z_{j,n} = k).
$$

Since for each $n$, $E(\sum_{j=1}^n Z_{j,n})= Var(\sum_{j=1}^n Z_{j,n}) = \lambda$, this reminds me of Poisson distribution. I found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) that this is called free Poisson distribution. But I did not find any helpful material elsewhere. Can someone point to how to approach this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Definition looks funny.  $\lambda_j $ depends on n and $\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: Doesn't the quantity $\sum_{j=1}^n Z_{j,n}$ obey a binomial distribution with $p = \lambda/n$?

Comment: Look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#As_a_Binomial_distribution_with_infinitesimal_time-steps) section of that Wikipedia article.

Comment: @JohnBarber But I think binomial distribution refers to the sum of i.i.d. variables. In my case, I don't think the $Z_{j,n}$'s are i.i.d. They are only independent but not necessarily have the same distribution.

Comment: But don't you say they're independent in the statement of the problem? "...there are independent random variables..." And they're definitely identically distributed for fixed $n$. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @herbsteinberg $\lambda$ is a fix number. See revised problem description.

Comment: @JohnBarber Oh I see. The $Z_{j,n}$'s are discrete random variables, so they do have the same distribution. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any given $n$ we have
$$
\mathbb P\left(\sum_{j=1}^n Z_{j,n}=k\right) = \binom nk \left(\frac\lambda n\right)^k\left(1-\frac\lambda n\right)^{n-k}.
$$
As $n\to\infty$ the above limit is $e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$, and hence $Z_{j,n}\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow \mathsf{Pois}(\lambda)$.

More generally it holds for a sequence $p_n$ of real numbers in $[0,1]$ such that $np_n\to \lambda$,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \binom nk p_n^k (1-p_n)^{n-k} = e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$$
(this is commonly known as the Poisson limit theorem).